# how to use lottie animation in my xamarin forms app?

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have use lottie animation from nuget package but when app is open its show nothing, my code is below
xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms"

```
<forms:AnimationView 
                    x:Name="animationView"  
                    Animation="data.json" 
                    Loop="True" 
                    AutoPlay="True"           
                    HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

i installed Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie 3.1.3 from nuget package but its not showing, kindly suggest....

Comment: Have you placed the 'data.json' on the platform specific project?  In Android for example, you have to put this file in the 'Assets' folder, and flag the file as 'AndroidAsset'?

Comment: yes, i already done that.

Comment: do you have a repo with this, and i will take a quick look?

Comment: when i changed the target framework version to 10.0 its working but in 9.0 its not working. and i have to write in mainactivity.cs "AnimationViewRenderer.Init(); and in appdelegate.cs

Comment: now i found that in target framework 10.0 its working but in 9.0 its not working

Comment: yes you have to initialize it via AnimationViewRenderer.Init().  So are you all good now?, or any issues?  If it works on framework 10, just stick to that, that's what I'm currently using on my Android project.

Comment: Any updates? I am targeting 10.0 and not working, also I believe they have removed the .Init() method @Pete.